# Recording with OpenSL ES in emulator

Tags: android, opensl

I am developing an app using OpenSLES for audio recording and playing. At this point, the app is similar to JNI sample native-audio app. One problem is that when program tries to record, it's getting following error in my emulator although it's fine in real devices.

```
12-07 16:09:44.014: E/AudioRecord(342): Unsupported configuration: sampleRate 16000, format 1, channelCount 1
```

And this is the line I am getting that error.

```
result = (*recorderObject)->Realize(recorderObject, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
if (SL_RESULT_SUCCESS != result) {
    return JNI_FALSE;
}
```

Of course, I set AVD with audio record and playing true and specified following in my Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

What else do I need to do to remove the error above?

Comment: What is the line of code in AudioRecord at 342? the problem is obviously there.

Comment: @Phonon I believe that's in Android library.

Comment: Have you tried different sampling rates? It might be that the emulator only supports one or very few.